# Dictionary to lowercase in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lowercase

I wish to do this but for a dictionary:

```
"My string".lower()
```

Is there a built in function or should I use a loop?

Comment: for the keys, values, or both?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You will need to use either a loop or a list/generator comprehension.  If you want to lowercase all the keys and values, you can do this::

```
dict((k.lower(), v.lower()) for k,v in {'My Key':'My Value'}.iteritems())
```

If you want to lowercase just the keys, you can do this::

```
dict((k.lower(), v) for k,v in {'My Key':'My Value'}.iteritems())
```

[Generator expressions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (used above) are often useful in building dictionaries; I use them all the time.  All the expressivity of a loop comprehension with none of the memory overhead.

Comment: This assumes the keys are strings. If you have a numeric value as a key it will fail.

Comment: `dict.iteritems()` is removed from Python 3 , instead use `dict.items()`.

Comment: what happens if there is an item 'A':4 and 'a':5. how can i add both up so it becomes 'a':9

Answer (score 16):

If you want keys and values of multi-nested dictionary (json format) lowercase, this might help.
Need to have support for dict comprehensions what should be in **Python 2.7**

```
dic = {'A':['XX', 'YY', 'ZZ'],
       'B':(u'X', u'Y', u'Z'),
       'C':{'D':10,
            'E':('X', 'Y', 'Z'),
            'F':{'X', 'Y', 'Z'}
           },
       'G':{'X', 'Y', 'Z'}
      }
```

***PYTHON2.7*** -- also supports OrderedDict

```
def _lowercase(obj):
    """ Make dictionary lowercase """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        t = type(obj)()
        for k, v in obj.items():
            t[k.lower()] = _lowercase(v)
        return t
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, set, tuple)):
        t = type(obj)
        return t(_lowercase(o) for o in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, basestring):
        return obj.lower()
    else:
        return obj
```

***PYTHON 3.6***

```
def _lowercase(obj):
    """ Make dictionary lowercase """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k.lower():_lowercase(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, set, tuple)):
        t = type(obj)
        return t(_lowercase(o) for o in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.lower()
    else:
        return obj
```

Comment: in python 3, use items(), instead of iteritems() and str instead of basestring, and if u dont want to lower your values, in my case they were lists, just remove the elif clause that checks list(lists can't be keys anyways)

Comment: this solution is for multi-nested dictionaries. I will add solution as @lava-lava suggested + add checking for set and tuples. In case of 2.7 version small alternation in dict creation to support OrderedDict (in 3.0 dict are ordered by def.)

Answer (score 15):

**Shorter way in python 3:** `{k.lower(): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}`

Comment: what abot the values?

Comment: {k.lower(): v.lower() for k, v in my_dict.items()}

Answer (score 14):

The following is identical to Rick Copeland's answer, just written without a using generator expression:

```
outdict = {}
for k, v in {'My Key': 'My Value'}.iteritems():
    outdict[k.lower()] = v.lower()
```

Generator-expressions, list comprehension's and (in Python 2.7 and higher) dict comprehension's are basically ways of rewriting loops.

In Python 2.7+, you can use a dictionary comprehension (it's a single line of code, but you can reformat them to make it more readable):

```
{k.lower():v.lower()
    for k, v in
    {'My Key': 'My Value'}.items()
}
```

They are quite often tidier than the loop equivalent, as you don't have to initialise an empty dict/list/etc.. but, if you need to do anything more than a single function/method call they can quickly become messy.

Comment: how to generalize this for a case where the dictionary has more than one keys and >1 values for each key?

Answer (score 5):

This will lowercase all your dict keys. Even if you have nested dict or lists. You can do something similar to apply other transformations.

```
def lowercase_keys(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, dict):
    obj = {key.lower(): value for key, value in obj.items()}
    for key, value in obj.items():         
      if isinstance(value, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(value):
          value[idx] = lowercase_keys(item)
      obj[key] = lowercase_keys(value)
  return obj
```

```
json_str = {"FOO": "BAR", "BAR": 123, "EMB_LIST": [{"FOO": "bar", "Bar": 123}, {"FOO": "bar", "Bar": 123}], "EMB_DICT": {"FOO": "BAR", "BAR": 123, "EMB_LIST": [{"FOO": "bar", "Bar": 123}, {"FOO": "bar", "Bar": 123}]}}

lowercase_keys(json_str)


Out[0]: {'foo': 'BAR',
 'bar': 123,
 'emb_list': [{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 123}, {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 123}],
 'emb_dict': {'foo': 'BAR',
  'bar': 123,
  'emb_list': [{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 123}, {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 123}]}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used JSON library to deserialize the dictionary first, apply lower case than convert back to dictionary

```
import json
mydict = {'UPPERCASE': 'camelValue'}
print(mydict)
mydict_in_str = json.dumps(mydict)
mydict_lowercase = json.loads(mydict_in_str.lower())
print(mydict_lowercase)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3:

```
d = dict()
d = {k.casefold(): v for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dictionary supplied have multiple type of key/values(numeric, string etc.); then use the following solution.

For example; if you have a dictionary named mydict as shown below

```
mydict = {"FName":"John","LName":"Doe",007:true}
```

**In Python 2.x**

```
dict((k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k, v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v) for k,v in mydict.iteritems())
```

**In Python 3.x**

```
dict((k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k, v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v) for k,v in mydict.iteritems())
```

**Note:** this works good on single dimensional dictionaries

Comment: At this point I would just make a lower function which does the check. `try_lower = lambda k: k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k`

Answer (score 2):

I am answering this late - as the question is tagged `Python`.
Hence answering with a solution for both `Python 2.x` and `Python 3.x`, and also handling the case of non-string keys.

**Python 2.x** - using dictionary comprehension

```
{k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v for k,v in yourDict.iteritems()}
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> yourDict = {"Domain":"WORKGROUP", "Name": "CA-LTP-JOHN", 111: 'OK', "Is_ADServer": 0, "Is_ConnectionBroker": 0, "Domain_Pingable": 0}
>>> {k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v for k,v in yourDict.iteritems()}
{'domain': 'workgroup', 'name': 'ca-ltp-john', 'is_adserver': 0, 'is_connectionbroker': 0, 111: 'ok', 'domain_pingable': 0}
```

---

**Python 3.x** - no `iteritems()` in Python 3.x

```
{k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in yourDict.items()}
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> dict((k.lower() if isinstance(k, basestring) else k, v.lower() if isinstance(v, basestring) else v) for k,v in yourDict.iteritems())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
>>> {k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k: v.lower() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in yourDict.items()}
>>> {'domain': 'workgroup', 'name': 'ca-ltp-john', 111: 'ok', 'is_adserver': 0, 'is_connectionbroker': 0, 'domain_pingable': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Love the way you can use multilevel functions, here's my way of lowercase-ing the keys

```
def to_lower(dictionary):

    def try_iterate(k):
        return lower_by_level(k) if isinstance(k, dict) else k

    def try_lower(k):
        return k.lower() if isinstance(k, str) else k

    def lower_by_level(data):
        return dict((try_lower(k), try_iterate(v)) for k, v in data.items())

    return lower_by_level(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Python 3` you can do:

```
dict((k.lower(), v.lower()) for k,v in {'Key':'Value'}.items())
```

In `Python 2` just substitute `.items()` for `.iteritems()`:

```
dict((k.lower(), v.lower()) for k,v in {'Key':'Value'}.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to subtype from UserDict, and that way all data inserted will have lower case key and you don't need to care about to lower case at access time:

```
from collections import UserDict
from typing import Any

class InsensitiveCaseDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key: Any) -> Any:
        if type(key) is str:
            return super().__getitem__(key.lower())
        return super().__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key: Any, item: Any) -> Any:
        if type(key) is str:
            self.data[key.lower()] = item
            return
        self.data[key] = item
```

And you can convert your original dict:

```
insensitive_case_dict = InsensitiveCaseDict(my_original_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vldbnc answer, if you only want to **lowercase the keys only in a nested dict** in python 3.x

```
def _dict_keys_lowercase(obj):
    """ Make dictionary lowercase """
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k.lower():_dict_keys_lowercase(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    else:
        return obj
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def convert_to_lower_case(data):
    if type(data) is dict:
        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            if type(v) is str:
                data[k] = v.lower()
            elif type(v) is list:
                data[k] = [x.lower() for x in v]
            elif type(v) is dict:
                data[k] = convert_to_lower_case(v)
    return data
```