# How to Iterate through the Keys of a Dictionary and Lowercase them?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, lowercase

I have this dictionary of lists:

```
Dict = {'Name':['John','Seth'], 'Gender':['Male','Male'], 'Zip':['68112','22200']}
```

How to iterate through the keys of this list and make them in lowercase?

The output should be like:

```
Dict = {'name':['John','Seth'], 'gender':['Male','Male'], 'zip':['68112','22200']}
```

I have reviewed the solution by [Rich Copeland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764235/dictionary-to-lowercase-in-python), but It was not evident to me how to apply.

Any idea how to solve this?

|

I figured out how to fix it!
here, use this:

```
Dict = {'Name':['John','Seth'], 'Gender':['Male','Male'], 'Zip':['68112','22200']}
for key in Dict:
    Dict[key.lower()] = Dict.pop(key)
print(Dict)
```

~Jack Burch

sorry, the thread was closed so I couldn't  comment it.

Comment: The post you linked is the exact solution to this.

Comment: if that answer is not enough for you, you should definately review some more beginner tutorials

Comment: This should do the trick: `{k.lower():Dict[k] for k in Dict.keys()}`

Comment: I got it now ... I am new to python and not used to dictionary comprehension notation.

Answer (score 1):

`{k.lower(): v for k,v in dict_.iteritems ()}`

Comment: this will only work for python 2.7 + (which is probably fine ...) ... and really doesnt add anything that the answer this was closed as duplicate doesnt cover... it should really be a comment instead of an answer