# Lowercase the keys in a dict

Tags: python

I have an array of `dict`s and I would like to lowercase the keys. Here is what I have so far:

```
d_lower = []
for item in d:
    item_lower = {k.lower():v for k,v in item.items()}
    d_lower.append(item_lower)
```

Can this be done in a single-line list-comprehension?

Comment: Isn't this the same question as in [Dictionary to lowercase in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/764235/4909087)?

Comment: @cs95 similar, this is an array of that though. But yea, same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, though it's not necessarily any more readable:

```
[{k.lower():v for k,v in item.items()} for item in d]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
{i.lower():j for i,j in d.items()}
```

where `d` is the dict.